# Stop infinite animation in preloader

Tags: javascript, css, animation, preloader

I´m now working on preloader for webpage, but cant figure how to stop the animation, so the javascript could to it's work and fade the preloader away.

Basically heres the whole situation and I just can't get it working right.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
$('.cssload-whirlpool').fadeOut();
$('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
$('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.cssload-container {
    position: relative;
}

.cssload-whirlpool,
.cssload-whirlpool::before,
.cssload-whirlpool::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 974px;
    -o-border-radius: 974px;
    -ms-border-radius: 974px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 974px;
    -moz-border-radius: 974px;
    
}

.cssload-whirlpool {
    margin: -24px 0 0 -24px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
}

.cssload-whirlpool::before {
    content: "";
    margin: -22px 0 0 -22px;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
}

.cssload-whirlpool::after {
    content: "";
    margin: -28px 0 0 -28px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
        <div class="cssload-whirlpool"></div>
</div>
```

Would appriciate any help :-)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to fade it out, remove it, stop the animation or something else?

Comment: The .preloader is z-index blank white page so get rid of it, so the webpage content under it will appear. It should work as fake preloading page.

Comment: It looks like it works to me after you include jQuery in the snippet... `$` is not defined, so you get an error and an infinite animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
$('.cssload-whirlpool').fadeOut();
$('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
$('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.cssload-container {
    position: relative;
}

.cssload-whirlpool,
.cssload-whirlpool::before,
.cssload-whirlpool::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 974px;
    -o-border-radius: 974px;
    -ms-border-radius: 974px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 974px;
    -moz-border-radius: 974px;
    
}

.cssload-whirlpool {
    margin: -24px 0 0 -24px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
}

.cssload-whirlpool::before {
    content: "";
    margin: -22px 0 0 -22px;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 1150ms linear infinite;
}

.cssload-whirlpool::after {
    content: "";
    margin: -28px 0 0 -28px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: cssload-rotate 2300ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-rotate {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
        <div class="cssload-whirlpool"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, yes. I had it under the custom script. Feel stupid now... Thank you and sorry for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid thing, but I got it working by implementing jQuery in my codepen.

```
// StackOverflow requires code in order to link codepens!
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.cssload-whirlpool').fadeOut();
    $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOokwG

EDIT: Turns out it wasn't :).